# Cannot deploy Rails application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, git-push

I've built a Rails app which I want to deploy on heroku. I can run the web application on my local machine. 
When I type the command : `git push heroku master` I get the following error message:

```
git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heruko.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It seems to be an connection error. So I tried:

```
sh -v git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version endosome
debug1: no match: endosome
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to heroku.com ([50.19.85.156]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = fr_FR.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Here I can see the authentication is successful. I don't understand why I cannot push on heroku and deploy my application.

Here are remote : 
git remote -v

```
heroku  git@heruko.com:aqueous-plateau-17182.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heruko.com:aqueous-plateau-17182.git (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:pracede/hubapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:pracede/hubapp.git (push)
```

Do you have an idea or a suggestion?

Comment: have you added ssh keys to heroku ?

Comment: @Pracede - Run `heroku keys` and check added keys are correct or not. And also check the heroku git repository added as a remote `git remote -v`

Comment: @LHH i added ssh key.

Comment: @VenkatCh how to see if added keys are correct. My test was to try to connect with ssh and authentication was succesful

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your git remotes:

> git@heruko.com:aqueous-plateau-17182.git

It's `heroku`, not `heruko` :)